# If + Past Simple + Future Simple

Tags: conditionals

I have come across the following quotation:

> If you knew how quickly people forget the dead... you will stop living to impress people.

Do you think that there is a mistake here, and the word 'would' must be used instead of 'will'? Or is this quotation grammatically correct? If yes, why is the word 'will' used here? What meaning does it convey?

Comment: Yes, it should be _would_.

Comment: Thank you so much, Kate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it's certainly "would."  You can get away with starting the antecedent with present and ending (consequent) with future.  And present then present.  But not subjunctive then future.

Correct:

- If preservatives aren't unhealthy, then I will be a monkey's uncle.
  Vs. If preservatives aren't unhealthy, then I am a monkey's uncle.
- If I am a man, then the moon will show up in the sky tonight.
- If I am a man, then the moon shows up in the sky tonight.

Incorrect:

- If I were a rich boy, then I will eat ham on Sundays.

Correct:

- If I were a camel, I wouldn't have to hydrate so often.

Logic bonus:

- If I am a camel, then the moon will show up in the sky tonight.

That is valid logic even though it is not true that I am a camel.

Comment: Thank you very much!